# How to access a different page when a user has selected a checkbox and click a button?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, checkbox

I have three checkbox for the users to select from. The third checkbox when it is selected display a form which allows the users to fill in a form and submit it as an email which is working. However what I wanted to do for the other two is to allow the users select any checkbox and then click on button which will take to their appropriate web pages. For example if a user select the checkbox to upload a file and then click a button "next" it will then then take them to the upload file web page.

I am still learning jquery so i would like a bit of help with the jquery/javascript code if it is possible. I have made attempt on the jquery code however i know im doing it right.

```
<form action="">            
    <input type="checkbox" name="radio-1" id="radio-1" onchange = "changeRadio()">
    <label for="radio-1">I Want to Upload my own artwork</label>
    </br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="radio-1" id="radio-1" onclick =>
    <label for="radio-1">I want to use a pre made template</label>
    </br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="createartwork" id="createartwork"> 
    <label class="label-for-check" for="createartwork">I want you to create my artwork</label> 
</form>


<div id="next-container">
    <button class="card__btn btn" id="nxtBtn" type="button" >Next</button>
</div>

$(function() {
    $('#radio-1').click(function() {
        $('#nxtBtn').prop(
            'disabled',
            (!$(this).prop('checked'))
        );
    });
});
```

Comment: so only if they select the checkbox, they should be shown the button?

Comment: can you show the javascript of what you have tried so far

Comment: @coder if the button is already already on the page, if they select a checkbox they will then have to click a button to go onto the next page, the checkbox plays as a confirmation for the web page the would like access

Comment: @prasad they can only select one at the time

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion here would be to change `checkbox` to `radio-group` with same name, and add a click event to `#nextBtn` button and get the selected value from radio group and based on the value, perform necessary action. To navigate to different page just use `location.href="your url";`. Below is the sample demo snippet for you.

```js
$("#nxtBtn").on('click', function() {
  var selected = $('input[name=radio-1]:checked', '#frmOptions').val()
  switch (selected) {
    case "1":
      alert("Redirect with location.href='www.someurl.com/newpage';");
      //replace alert with location.href="your url";
      break;
    case "2":
      alert("Redirect with location.href='www.someurl.com/newpage2';");
      //replace alert with location.href="your url";
      break;
    case "3":
      alert("Display Your form");
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="frmOptions" action="">
  <input type="radio" value="1" checked name="radio-1" id="radio-1" />
  <label for="radio-1">I Want to Upload my own artwork</label>
  <br/>
  <input type="radio" value="2" name="radio-1" id="radio-2" />
  <label for="radio-2">I want to use a pre made template</label>
  <br/>
  <input type="radio" value="3" name="radio-1" id="createartwork">
  <label class="label-for-check" for="createartwork">I want you to create my artwork</label>
  <br/>
  <div id="next-container">
    <button class="card__btn btn" id="nxtBtn" type="button">Next</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Sure.. Do not forget to upvote and mark as answer if it helped.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could hide the Next button until an option is selected, this will force the user to make a selection before proceeding. The following solution will set the form action based upon the radio button selection.

```
<style>
    .hidden {
      visibility: hidden;
    }
</style>

<script>
  $().ready(function() {
    $("input[name=artwork]:radio").click(function() {
      var url = "http://url.com/default";
      // get the value from the input field
      switch(this.value) {
        case "create" :
          url = "http://url.com/create";
          break;
        case "premade" :
          url = "http://url.com/premade";
          break;
        case "upload" :
          url = "http://url.com/upload";
          break;
      });
      // set the form target
      $("#artwork_form").attr("target", url);
      // display the button container
      $("#next-container").removeClass("hidden");
    }
  });
</script>

<form name="artwork_form" id="artwork_form" action="">
  <input type="radio" name="artwork" value="upload">
  <label>I Want to Upload my own artwork</label>
  <br/>
  <input type="radio" name="artwork" value="premade">
  <label>I want to use a pre made template</label>
  <br/>
  <input type="radio" name="artwork" value="create">
  <label>I want you to create my artwork</label>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <div id="next-container" class="hidden">
    <input type="submit" id="nxtBtn" value="Next">
  </div>
</form>
```